# Slow Rust Performance for a SSH Log Parsing project

Tags: performance, optimization, rust

I'm a student who is interested in learning rust. For a class project I wrote a rust script that parses a SSH log file, which specifically captured dates and IP addresses in the log.

When I first finished the project, the script took 3 minutes to run through a log file with 655147 entries. After major optimizations I got the processing down to 30 seconds. This is fine, but other students' python programs did it in 3 seconds. So I know it's definitely my fault and I want to know how to write it better. Could someone show me where I went wrong?

Here are the structs I made for reference:

```rust
struct DateLogins {
    date: NaiveDate,
    success: i32,
    failure: i32,
}

struct IpAuth {
    success: i32,
    failure: i32,
    first_attempt: NaiveDateTime,
    successful_attempt: NaiveDateTime,
    failed_reverse: bool,
    break_in_attempt: bool,
    ip_addr: String,
}

struct MinedReport {
    start_date: NaiveDateTime,
    end_date: NaiveDateTime,
    total_success: i32,
    total_failure: i32,
    total_addrs: i32,
    login_attempts: HashMap<String, DateLogins>,
    unique_addrs: HashMap<String, IpAuth>,
}
```

And here is the main processing logic:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref IP_RGX: Regex = Regex::new(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\d\.\d{1,3})").unwrap();  // regex for capturing the IP address of a message.
    static ref LOGIN_GOOD_RGX: Regex = Regex::new(r"Accepted password").unwrap();   // regex for successful login attempts -- for total, date, and IP address.
    static ref LOGIN_FAIL_RGX: Regex = Regex::new(r"Failed password").unwrap();     // regex for failed login attempts -- for total, date, and IP address
    static ref REVERSE_LOOK_RGX: Regex = Regex::new(r"reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo").unwrap();  // regex for a failed reverse lookup
    static ref BREAK_IN_RGX: Regex = Regex::new(r"POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!").unwrap();    // regex for a break in attempt -- for IP address
}

fn main() {

    let start: std::time::Instant;
    let duration: std::time::Duration;

    let file: File = File::open("./SSH.log").expect("Could not open log file!");
    let reader: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(file);

    let origin_date: NaiveDateTime = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("0000 01 01 00:00:00", "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S").expect("Could not parse start time!");
    let mut report: MinedReport = MinedReport::new(origin_date.clone(), origin_date.clone());
    start = Instant::now();
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let l = line.expect("Could not read a line!");
        parse_line(l, &mut report, origin_date);
    }
    duration = start.elapsed();

    store_log(report, "./report.txt");

    println!("Total time elapsed: {:?}\n", duration);
}

// parses the values in each line
fn parse_line(line: String, report: &mut MinedReport, origin_date: NaiveDateTime) {
    let time: &str = &line[..15];
    let message: &str = &line[15..];
    
    // parse the time to DateTime. Store things in the report.
    let date_time: NaiveDateTime = parse_time(time, report, origin_date).unwrap();
    
    // parse the IP address of the line. Store things in the report.
    parse_ip(message, report, origin_date, date_time);
}

// parses the time value for each line.
fn parse_time(time_cap: &str, report: &mut MinedReport, origin_date: NaiveDateTime) -> Result<NaiveDateTime, ParseError> {
    // add a random year just to have a string.
    let time_str: String = time_cap.to_string();
    let full_date: String;
    let date_time: NaiveDateTime;
    let date: NaiveDate;
    let d: String;

    // add a year. Move to the next year if it's january.
    // (I know this is a bad solution, but the only months in the log are Dec and Jan, with no year)
    if &time_str[..3] == "Dec" {
        full_date = format!("{}{}", "0000 ", time_cap); // No year given, set it to 0000
    } else {
        full_date = format!("{}{}", "0001 ", time_cap); // No year given, set it to 0001
    }
    
    // get date time and date only.
    date_time = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&full_date, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S").unwrap();
    date = date_time.date();
    d = date.to_string();

    if report.start_date == origin_date {
        report.start_date = date_time;
    }
    report.end_date = date_time;

    if !report.login_attempts.contains_key(&d) {
        report.login_attempts.insert(d, DateLogins::new(date));
    }

    Ok(date_time)
}

fn parse_ip(message: &str, report: &mut MinedReport, origin_date: NaiveDateTime, current_date: NaiveDateTime) {
    for ip in IP_RGX.captures_iter(message) {
        let new_ip: String = String::from(&ip[1]);
        let ip_clone: String = new_ip.clone();
        let date: NaiveDate = current_date.date();
        let d: String = date.to_string();

        report.total_addrs += 1;
        
        if !report.unique_addrs.contains_key(&new_ip) {
            report.unique_addrs.insert(new_ip, IpAuth::new(ip_clone.clone(), origin_date.clone(), current_date.clone()));
        }

        let login_date = report.login_attempts.get_mut(&d).unwrap();
        let unique_ip = report.unique_addrs.get_mut(&ip_clone).unwrap();

        if LOGIN_FAIL_RGX.is_match(message) {
            report.total_failure += 1;
            login_date.failure += 1;
            unique_ip.failure += 1;
        } else if LOGIN_GOOD_RGX.is_match(message) {
            report.total_success += 1;
            login_date.success += 1;
            unique_ip.success += 1;
            unique_ip.successful_attempt = current_date.clone();
        } else {
            if REVERSE_LOOK_RGX.is_match(message) {
                unique_ip.failed_reverse = true;
            }

            if BREAK_IN_RGX.is_match(message) {
                unique_ip.break_in_attempt = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said I'm new to rust, and programming in general, so there may be something I just don't know about. I already switched to using a hash map from a vector, but maybe there's something better I can use? I don't know. I have also wondered if the `chrono` or `regex` crates are my issue here and maybe there's a faster alternative. Either way, thanks to anyone who tries to understand and correct my code!

Comment: Mandatory optimization remark: are you using the `--release` flag in your `cargo` commands, aren't you? I've noticed that the debug version of the regex crate is particularly slow.

Comment: I actually wasn't using the `--release` flag. I had no idea about it. Thank you, that brought it down to 1.3 seconds!